# SQL find same column data

Tags: php, sql, mysql

I have a table with around 15 columns. What I would like to be able to do, is select a range of IDs and have all column data that is the same, presented to me.

At the minute, I have it structured as the following:

```
SELECT id, col_a, col_b ... count(id)
FROM table
GROUP BY col_a, col_b ...
```

Which returns rows grouped together that have identical data within all the rows - which is half what I want, but ideally I would like to be able to get a single row with either the value (if it's the same for every row id) or NULL if there is a single difference.

I'm not sure that it is possible, but I would rather see if it's doable in an SQL query than write some looping logic for PHP to go through and check each row's similarity.

Thanks,

Dan

UPDATE:

Just to keep this up-to-date, I worked through the problem by writing a PHP function that would find which were duplicates and then display the differences. However I have now since made a table for each column, and made the columns as references to the other tables.

E.G. In MainTable, ColA now refers to the table ColA

I'm still solving the problem with the PHP for the time being, mainly as I think it still leaves the problem mentioned above, but at least now Im not storing duplicate information.

Comment: I wonder if you shouldn't refactor your database architecture? The whole idea of having a relational database is to prevent storing the same data in different places. There may be a perfectly valid reason for doing such things though. User input comes to mind... but I would validate the data before storing it in a db.

Comment: Its based on an image library, and each image has data associated with it. Some images share the same data, and when editing the data of multiple images, the people I'm doing it for want all the information that is the 'same' to be displayed for them.

Comment: An example of the actual table structure as well as actual data would be greatly appreciated. At the moment your table looks like it suffering from great structure flaws and misconceptions.

Comment: The table structure from before was simply a table with about 15 or so columns, which stored image 'metadata', so a range of longtext fields and blob fields. Now this is changed so all the 15 columns are now ints, and reference the tables containing the information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a hairy thing to do, but you could do it similarly to how David Martensson suggested, I would write it like this, however:

```
Select a.id, a.col1, a.col2, a.col3
FROM myTable a, myTable b
WHERE a.id != b.id
and a.col1 = b.col1
and a.col2 = b.col2
and a.col3 = b.col3
```

That would give you the ids that are unique, but each result would have the same values for columns 1, 2, and 3.  However, I agree with some of the commenters to your question that you should consider an alternative data structure, as this could better take advantage of an RDBMS model.  In that case you would want to have 2 tables:

Table name: MyTableIds
Fields: id, attrId

Table name: MyTableAttrs
Fields: attrId, attr1, attr2, attr3, ect

In general, if you have data that is going to be duplicated for multiple records, you should pull it into a second table and create a relationship so that you only have to store the duplicated data 1 time and then reference it multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Make a join to a subquery with the group by:

```
SELECT a.id, b.col_a, b.col_b ... b.count)
FROM table a 
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT id, col_a, col_b ... count(id) "count"
    FROM table GROUP BY col_a, col_b ...
)b on a.id = b.id
```

That way the outer will select all rows.

If you still want to group answers you could use a UNION instead

```
SELECT id, col_a ...
WHERE id NOT IN ("SUBQUERY WITH GROUP BY")
UNION
"SUBQUERY WITH GROUP BY"
```

Not the nicest solution but it should work

Answer (score 0):

It seems doable from how I have understood your question.

And here's a possible pattern:

```
SELECT
  /* GROUP BY columns */
  col_A,
  col_B,
  ...

  /* aggregated columns */
  CASE MIN(col_M) WHEN MAX(col_M) THEN MIN(col_M) ELSE NULL END,
  CASE MIN(col_N) WHEN MAX(col_N) THEN MIN(col_N) ELSE NULL END,
  ...
  COUNT(...),
  SUM(...),
  WHATEVER(...),
  ...
FROM ...
GROUP BY col_A, col_B, ...
```

Comment: WHATEVER() is implemented silently. That's the function that runs when you have columns in the SELECT clause that aren't in a GROUP BY clause. (cough)

Comment: @Catcall: Actually yes, you are right, thanks! Somehow that didn't cross my mind when I was making up that jocular name for an arbitrary aggregate. I need to be more careful next time.